# RxJs how to merge two overlapping observable into one

Tags: merge, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two observables:

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-|
-13--14--15--16--17--18--19-----20---------21--------------22------23--24-->
```

The first contains some increasing number, but stops after a while (these are the cursor result from the database)
The second are continuously emitting increasing number. Contains some number from the first, but don't stop emitting. (These are the newly inserted data to the database)

I want this two observable to look one continuous observable like this:

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-----22------23--24-->
```

This observable contains every number only once, keeping the emission order.

How can it be solved with using as less memory as possible?

Comment: Wondering how did you get such two overlapping Observables streams? What is their meaning in your problem?

Comment: I use Rethinkdb. I have old data in the database which is readed by the cursor, and newly inserted data, which is emitted by the changefeed. While I read the data from the cursor, the newly inserted data also readed by the cursor. That cause the overlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to buffer b$ until a$ stream reaches b$, then emit all the buffered items of b$ and switch to b$. Something like this:

```js
const a = '-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15';
const b = '-13--14--15--16--17--18--19-----20---------21--------------22------23--24';

const fromMarble = str => Rx.Observable.from(str.split('-')).concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(x).delay(1)).filter(v => v.length).map(x => parseInt(x));

const a$ = fromMarble(a).share();
const b$ = fromMarble(b).share();

const switchingSignal$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a$, b$.take(1), (a, b) => a >= b).filter(x => x).take(1).share();

const distinct$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
 a$.takeUntil(switchingSignal$).map(x => x + '(from a)'), 
 b$.buffer(switchingSignal$).take(1).mergeMap(buffered => Rx.Observable.from(buffered)).map(x => x + '(from b$ buffer)'),
 b$.skipUntil(switchingSignal$).map(x => x + '(from b$)')
);

distinct$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by taking all elements from the first stream concatenated(`.concat`) with the second stream except(`.skipWhile` inclusive) elements before the latest one (`.last`)

```js
const a = '-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15'
const b = '-13--14--15--16--17--18--19-----20---------21--------------22------23--24'
const fromMarble = str => Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
  console.log('side effect from subscribing to: ' + str);
  return Rx.Observable.from(str.split('-').filter(v => v.length));
});

const a$ = fromMarble(a);
const b$ = fromMarble(b);

const distinct$ = Rx.Observable.concat(
  a$,
  a$.last().switchMap(latest =>
    // .skipWhile + .skip(1) => skipWhile but inclusive
    b$.skipWhile(v => v !== latest).skip(1)
  ),
);

distinct$.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Also if you have side-effects when subscribing(for example when you subscribe - the new cursor will be created) you can share that side-effect for all subscribers by using for example `const a$ = fromMarble(a).shareReaplay()`.

You can read more about sharing side-effects:

- in the old documentation for RxJS v4 - [4.8 Use the publish operator to share side-effects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines#48-use-the-publish-operator-to-share-side-effects)
- and from this article - [RxSwift: share vs replay vs shareReplay](https://medium.com/@_achou/rxswift-share-vs-replay-vs-sharereplay-bea99ac42168)

Comment: Nice solution. But, in case the b$ stream emits after the a$ stream, the distinct$ stream will be unnecessarily delayed. Not sure if it is an issue, but it could be solved without a delay.

Comment: Nice catch @ZahiC and another problem are when `b$` is empty - you'll get nothing. So I've modified my answer to handle that cases too

Comment: That's definitely solve the delay if b$ emits after a$, but now you might subscribed to b$ too late (the concatenated stream is subscribed when the first stream completes). If the b$ subscription takes time (e.g. connects to a db), switching to b$ will be slower. You can solve this by connecting to b$ sooner (hot Observable), but then you might lose some items. I will add another solution just for reference